# User specific hosts file in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, dns, hosts

I'm working on an OS X 10.6.8 machine, for which I do not have superuser privileges.

I'd like to imitate the effect of adding an entry to the hosts file, i.e. have a certain domain resolve to a certain ip.

Is it possible to add configuration to my home directory to achieve this? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Is this only through command line, or do you require this functionality through a browser/application too?

Comment: Only on the command line is fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

unfortunately the answer is no. Here's another answer to a very similar question. It's not the same question, but the answer is the same:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5007150/62653

As a side note, you might be interested in this blog post. It won't solve your problem, but is quite interesting nonetheless (the domain name for this address, and the blog title is a bit unfortunate, but it is a genuine blog entry on cocoa dev).

http://niggazpullintriggaz.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/how-i-managed-to-edit-etchosts-without.html